# How to ignore ts error in react production build?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

In my react project, I'm using `npm ci --production` to avoid unnecessary devDependencies downloads like typescript, and other library's types. But because of that I got ts errors when I run `npm run build`. How can I avoid downloading devDependencies and run `npm run build` without error?